# Is it possible to change the repository that a package is updated from?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

I currently have a package installed from
http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 Packages

A later version exists and I would like to update to that version, the developer has published a ppa for installation and updating of the package.
Is it possible to update from that ppa repo instead of the ubuntu archive?
The only way I am aware of is to uninstall the package installed from the ubuntu archive and install it from the developers ppa.  But I would like to avoid reconfiguring the application and was hoping I could simply 'point' the app to the  developers ppa?

Comment: What is the application and what is the feature that you need to have in the newer version that is not available in the current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the ppa to your system and the version of the app in the ppa is newer, when you run `sudo apt update` your system will point to the newer version and when you do `sudo apt upgrade` it will upgrade to it.

You do not need to uninstall the current version except for some edge cases like video drivers.

You can use the command `apt policy [packagename]` to see the available versions before and after you add the ppa.

Here is an example of one such package on my system

```
apt policy rhythmbox
rhythmbox:
  Installed: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~ubuntu1804
  Candidate: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~ubuntu1804
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~ubuntu1804 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.4.2-4ubuntu1 500
        500 ssh://[local mirror]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Haven't tried `apt policy` yet. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I have noticed this in the past and wondered why the package I tried didn't work.  It turns out that 20.10 groovy is not supported officially.